# Extreme troubles with full line input. C Programming Language

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, fgets

I am having the absolute craziest time getting full line input to work. I will explain my problem. I need to get a full line of input, *including* a space, from the user entered at the keyboard. Simple right? Wrong!

#### MY GOAL

Store multiple strings, with spaces, into variables. If it makes a difference, I want to make the variables equal to a `char` pointer. So once I get the input from `tempString`, I want to set it to a `char` pointer. Like so:

```
char *variable1, *variable2;
//get user input
variable1 = tempString;
//get more user input
variable 2 = tempString;
//etc etc etc
```

Here's what I've tried.

#### First try

```
char tempString[100];
scanf("%s", &tempString);
printf("%s", tempString);
```

Invalid: `scanf` will stop reading at a white space, so "`Example String`" would just end up being "`Example`".

#### Second try

So I do more research. I thought I found the magic fix.

```
char tempSTring[100];
fgets(tempString, 100, stdin);
printf("%s", tempString);
```

Originally this works. However there is a massive problem. I need to get the user to enter about 8 inputs. Meaning I have to use a command like this 8 times. The problem is the program often skips over the `fgets` command. If I use a `scanf` previously, somehow the `\n` character is stuck in the input stream, and automatically feeds into `fgets`, satisfying its `stdin input`, and then does not prompt the user for input.

#### Third try

After thinking `fgets` was maybe my solution with a work around, I tried some tricks.

```
char tempSTring[100];
getc(stdin);
fgets(tempString, 100, stdin);
printf("%s", tempString);
```

I tried adding this `getc(stdin)` line. It worked for much of my program. It absorbs the `\n` character left behind in the stream. When it does so, great, it works. But sometimes, for some reason, the `\n` is NOT left in the stream, and when debugging, it looks like `getc(stdin)` is requesting input from the user, so it pauses my program to ask for input.

#### Question

These don't work for me.

- How should I be doing this easy task?

Comment: Using `scanf()` in any of its variants for line-based input is a non-starter for most people.  It can be done; you're better off not trying.

Comment: Are you on a POSIX platform?  If so, [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) is your friend.  It will read a line and allocate the necessary space (via `malloc()`).  You can make it allocate for each line with a small modicum of care.  Otherwise, use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html), but make the buffer size far bigger than 100; I use 4096 by default, because few people write complete essays on a single line (but JSON can end up like that).

Comment: Also, [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) (another POSIX function — not standard C) is very useful.

Answer (score 6):

To read (up to) 8 lines from a file, you can use either of these solutions.  I decline to use variables `char *variable1, *variable2, …;` — that is an array seeking to escape.

## POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { MAX_LINES = 8 };
    char *lines[MAX_LINES];
    int   index = 0;
    char *buffer = 0;
    size_t buflen = 0;

    while (index < MAX_LINES && getline(&buffer, &buflen, stdin) != -1)
    {
        lines[index++] = buffer;
        buffer = 0;
        buflen = 0;
    }
    free(buffer);  // Space may be allocated before EOF is detected

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        printf("%d: %s", i, lines[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

If `getline()` fails to allocate memory, it will report an error, so there is no need to do an explicit error check.

#### Standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html)

Code using [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html), another POSIX function.  It isn't a part of standard C (though it is widely available).  It is trivial to implement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { MAX_LINES = 8 };
    char *lines[MAX_LINES];
    int   index = 0;
    char   buffer[4096];

    while (index < MAX_LINES && fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        if ((lines[index] = strdup(buffer)) == 0)
            break;
        index++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
        printf("%d: %s", i, lines[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The test in the loop allows for the possibility of `strdup()` failing to allocate memory.

#### Notes

Both the solutions above keep the newline at the end of the input string.  If you don't want that, you can zap it with:

```
lines[i][strcspn(lines[i], "\r\n")] = '\0';
```

This overwrites a carriage return or newline with a null byte, transforming DOS or Unix line endings.  You then need to adjust the printing which assumes the string includes a newline.  Note that the expression shown works correctly even if there is no carriage return or newline in the string.

The `fgets()` solution will break lines at 4095 characters, leaving the rest to be read as 'the next line'.  If that's not acceptable, you have a variety of strategies open to you.

1. You can detect whether there is a newline and arrange to allocate more memory and read the next section of the line into the extra memory, repeating until you come across a newline or EOF.
2. You can read the remaining characters up to the newline or EOF:

   ```
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
       ;
   ```

#### Implementing `strdup()`

If for some reason your system doesn't have an implementation of `strdup()`, you can create a surrogate with:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strdup(const char *old_str)
{
    assert(old_str != 0);
    size_t old_len = strlen(old_str) + 1;
    char *new_str = malloc(old_len);
    if (new_str != 0)
        memmove(new_str, old_str, old_len);
    return new_str;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `memmove` instead of `memcpy` in your surrogate implementation of `strdup`?  `old_str` and `new_str` cannot possibly overlap, so `memcpy` can be used safely and is move likely to be inlined than `memmove`.

Comment: Also, `if ((lines[index++] = strdup(buffer)) == 0)` seems risky: `i` should not be incremented if `strdup` fails, otherwise you pass `NULL` to `printf`.  Although most `printf` implementations will handle `NULL` for `%s` gracefully, it is not allowed by the C standard.

Comment: @chqrlie: I always use `memmove()` because it always works correctly and I decline to have anything to do with `memcpy()` because it doesn't always work correctly.  YMMV.

Comment: Sounds like a sound embodiment of the KISS philosophy to result in bulletproof code. So basically what you are saying is any incremental time required to protect against overlapping storage is more than worth the tradeoff...?

Comment: @chqrlie: regarding `if ((lines[index++] = strdup(buffer)) == 0)` — yes, you're right.  I originally had the test in the print loop and not the read loop, and didn't do the changes quite carefully enough.  Yes, you're right: too many `printf()` implementations don't crash like they should when passed a null pointer for a string — a sad commentary on how often they get abused.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: There's I/O involved here: I don't believe the difference between `memmove()` and `memcpy()` would be measurable.  If it is, I would tend to regard the implementation (of `memmove()`) as broken w.r.t performance.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just curious, why use `assert` instead of simply `if (!old_str)` and then `if (!*old_str)`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I use `assert(old_str != 0)` so developers get told they're doing it wrong.  I don't check `!*old_str` (which I'd write as `*old_str != '\0'`) because `strdup()` needs to make an independently freeable copy of an empty string if one is provided.

Comment: There is no I/O involved in the surrogate implementation of `strdup()` itself, and if you are not concerned about performance but favor readability, why not use `strcpy()`?  I do agree that performance of the actual program reading 8 lines would hardly matter and any measurable difference would not be significant.

Comment: @chqrlie: Agreed; there isn't I/O in `strdup()` per se. Using `strcpy()` means the code has to test for the null byte on each iteration; using `memmove()` it doesn't.  I've never found the performance difference between `memmove()` and `memcpy()` to matter to me (I've never been able to spot the difference).  I noted YMMV (your mileage may vary) in my first response about using `memmove()`. I didn't say "thou shalt use `memmove()`"; I only indicated that "I use `memmove()`".  I have nothing further to add — you may do as you wish with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how we old fart C programmers would do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

int main( )
{
    int c;
    char input[MAX_LEN+1];
    int i = 0;

    while ( (c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF && i < MAX_LEN)
        input[i++] = c;
    if (c == EOF || c =='\n') {
        /* received input that terminated within buffer limit */
        input[i] = '\0';
        printf("read in your input string of: %s\n", input);
    }
    else {
        printf("don't buffer overflow me dude!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

But nowadays people will tell you to use one of the library functions.  I'm still an old fart though.

**EDIT**: Fixed my embarrassing mistakes pointed out by the helpful comments below.

Comment: Hi old fart! looks like you forgot to set a `'\0'` at the end of `input` before passing it to `printf`...

Comment: @chqrlie: maybe that's because he didn't want to write beyond the end of the buffer if the line is longer than MAX_LEN?  At the very least, the code would need to be reviewed carefully to safely add a null if the line is too long.  There's also the issue of 'what to do with the surplus data on the line' if it is too long.  Leave it there to be read by the next lot of 'line input'?

Comment: The code indeed needs to be reviewed carefully: the `while` loop is incorrect too!  The check for `EOF` is missing, so the code will misbehave at the end of file, filling the buffer with funny characters.  It should be written: `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < MAX_LEN)...`  The next test is incorrect as well: `input[MAX_LEN-1] != '\n'` cannot be true because `'\n'` is never stored into `input[i]`, the test should be `if (i == MAX_LEN && c != EOF && c != '\n')`.  And the buffer should be allocated to a size of `MAX_LEN+1` to accommodate for the `'\0'`.

Comment: Why waste time with `memset` when a single store after the loop suffices: `input[i] = '\0';`

Comment: @chqrlie You are absolutely right.  My skills are so rusty.

Comment: Sorry to be so picky, your latest attempt still has problems: `if (i <= MAX_LEN)` is always true since you break out of the loop if `i == MAX_LEN`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take care of `'\n'` left by previous `scanf` by writing it like this -

```
scanf("%d%*c", &x);     //<-- example to take int input
```

`%*c` will read from `stdin` and then discard it, thus `'\n'` would be removed from `stdin`.

You can achieve with `scanf` like this (*a way for your previous attempt*)-

```
char tempString[100];
/* As suggested by chqrile it is essential to check return of scanf */
if(scanf("%99[^\n]", tempString)!=1){   
                //  ^^ & not required
     tempString[0]='\0';
}
```

`%99[^\n]` this will read `99` characters and will stop only after encountering `'\n'` , thus would read input with spaces.

Comment: There is one caveat with the `scanf("%99[^\n]"...)` solution: it cannot handle empty lines.  If the user enters a newline directly, `scanf` will fail and return `0`, leaving `tempString` uninitialized. This special case should be accounted for this way: `if (scanf("%99[^\n]", tempString) != 1) { tempString[0] = '\0'; }`

Comment: Your first fix seems to be working:

     scanf("%d%*c", &x);

Do you mind explaining more in detail? I'm sorry as I know you already did. I'm confused as to why you used %d (for an integer?) 

     scanf("%s%*c", &x);

Should I do this instead? So basically, I just do the same scanf inputs I've been doing, but at an additional %*c at the end?

Comment: @chqrlie Yes you are correct , `return` of `scanf` should be checked. I forgot to do that (_would be harmful for OP_). I will sure correct that .

Comment: @iHateC That was an example to take **integer input** . If you want to take input a string use specifier `%[^\n]` for that but with checking return of `scanf` as mentioned by _chqrile_ . What `%*c` has special is that it would read value from `stdin` but instead of stroring it will be discarded.